# EditingInline_Destroy isnt calling method in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I can't call EditingInline_Destroy method after click "delete" row in my kendo grid. Im getting monit from web browser if im surely to delete this row.
Editing is working properly.

Its my grid in View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TempPrivilagesModel>("Privilages")
          .Name("Uprawnienia")

      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(a => a.name);
          columns.Bound(a => a.abc);
          columns.Bound(a => a.def);
          columns.Bound(a => a.ghi);
          columns.Bound(a => a.jki);
          columns.Bound(a => a.qqwe);
          columns.Bound(a => a.tte);

          columns.Command(command =>
          {
              command.Edit();
              command.Destroy();
          });
      })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Scrollable()
      .Editable()
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .PageSize(20)
      .Model(model => model.Id(p=>p.Id))
                .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Settings"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Settings"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Settings"))
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Settings"))

      )

)
```

and actions in Settings controller :

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditingInline_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, TempPrivilagesModel privilages)
{

       return View();
}
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult EditingInline_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, TempPrivilagesModel product)
{
       return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```